# Replace row value with empty string if duplicate

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

is it possible to replace row value with empty string if duplicate value found?

For example

```
SELECT ProductCode, Color FROM Product

--------------------
ProductCode | Color
--------------------
   00A0B    |  Red
   00A0B    |  Blue
   00A0C    |  Red
   00A0C    |  Black
   00A0C    |  White
--------------------
```

to

```
--------------------
ProductCode | Color
--------------------
   00A0B    |  Red
            |  Blue
   00A0C    |  Red
            |  Black
            |  White
--------------------
```

I'm using SQL Server 2012.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Often, this type of transformation is better done at the application layer, because the result-set is not "SQL-ish".  That is, the ordering is important for understanding the rows.

But, you can do this as:

```
select (case when row_number() over (partition by ProductCode order by (select NULL)) = 1
             then ProductCode
        end) as ProductCode
       Color
from Product
order by ProductCode;
```

Comment: is `row_number()` sql default function or is it made up?

Comment: @Karen . . . I have no idea what your comment means.  `ROW_NUMBER()` is part of ANSI SQL and has been for two decades.

Comment: Thank you so very much. I was busting my head against the wall for hours trying to figure out how to remove or rename duplicate values, and this did it. You Rock, Gordon. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Use `ROW_NUMBER` and `CASE`:

```
WITH Cte AS(
    SELECT *,
        Rn = ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY ProductCode ORDER BY (SELECT NULL))
    FROM Product
)
SELECT
    ProductCode = CASE WHEN Rn = 1 THEN c.ProductCode ELSE '' END,
    Color 
FROM Cte c
ORDER BY c.ProductCode
```

Answer (score 0):

```
ROW_NUMBER() helps to find duplicate record : 

 SELECT Productcode=( CASE
                           WHEN rn > 1 THEN ''
                           ELSE Productcode
                         END ),
           color
    FROM   (SELECT Row_number()
                     OVER (
                       partition BY productcode
                       ORDER BY productcode) AS rn,
                   *
            FROM   table)a
```