# Replace DataRow value with empty string if duplicate in DataTable

Tags: c#, datatable

Is it possible to replace row value with empty string if duplicate value found?

For example

```
--------------------
ProductCode | Color
--------------------
   00A0B    |  Red
   00A0B    |  Blue
   00A0C    |  Red
   00A0C    |  Black
   00A0C    |  White
--------------------
```

to

```
--------------------
ProductCode | Color
--------------------
   00A0B    |  Red
            |  Blue
   00A0C    |  Red
            |  Black
            |  White
--------------------
```

Comment: Have you tried anything so far?

Comment: no, but i originally want to do this in my stored procedure, but a user suggests me to do that in application layer which make sense. I was thinking about iterating the datarow but I guess it's not a good idea performance wise.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33138663/replace-row-value-with-empty-string-if-duplicate

Comment: This solution applies to gridview, but might help. http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/34337/How-to-merge-cells-with-equal-values-in-a-GridView

Comment: thanks, I wrote an extension based on your answer.

Comment: Application layer doesn't mean datatable/datagrid necessarily. A reporting tool will do it for you automatically.

Comment: Do you have option to use linq in your case? I have done similar with linq previously. Let me know so i can provide the example for same.

Answer (score 1):

I wrote an extension for this.

```
    public static DataTable Dedup(this DataTable dt, string columnName)
    {
        for (int rowIndex = dt.Rows.Count - 1; rowIndex >= 1; rowIndex--)
        {
            var row = dt.Rows[rowIndex][columnName];
            var previousRow = dt.Rows[rowIndex - 1][columnName];

            if (row.ToString() == previousRow.ToString())
            {
                dt.Rows[rowIndex][columnName] = "";
            }
        }

        return dt;
    }
```

How to use :

```
DataTable dt = _product.GetProduct();
dt.Dedup("ProductCode");
```