# How to get Records Without Duplication Using Inner Join in SQL

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, asp.net-mvc

i'm Trying to get rid of duplicate records which is coming from parent Table i use self join. so how can i get rid of duplicate records from parent table.
My Table Structure Look LIke this

```
ID      CategoryName    ParentID    IsActive
----+----------------+-----------+-----------
1   |   Toyota       |   NULL    |     1    
2   |   Honda        |   NULL    |     1    
3   |   Mitsubhi     |   NULL    |     1    
4   |   Toyota GLI   |     1     |     1    
5   |   Toyota XLI   |     1     |     1    
6   |   Swift        |     1     |     1    
7   |   Honda Civic  |     2     |     1    
8   |   Honda City   |     2     |     1
```

I have already try self join with group by command & order by but its now working

```
select a.CatogoryName,b.CatogoryName
from CategoryInfo a inner join
     CategoryInfo b
     on a.Id= b.ParentId
Group By a.CatogoryName, b.CatogoryName
```

Result

```
Category Name     Model
Honda             Honda City
Honda             Honda Civic
Toyota            Swift
Toyota            Toyota GLI
Toyota            Toyota XLI
```

I use this query

```
select a.CatogoryName, b.CatogoryName
from CategoryInfo a inner join
     CategoryInfo b
     on a.Id = b.ParentId
```

Result

```
Category Name     Model
Honda             Honda City
Honda             Honda Civic
Toyota            Swift
Toyota            Toyota GLI
Toyota            Toyota XLI
```

Expected Result

```
Category Name     Model
Honda             Honda City
                  Honda Civic
Toyota            Swift
                  Toyota GLI
                  Toyota XLI
```

I Expected to single category name  Like this

Comment: This type of formatting is better done as the application level.

Comment: This is something for your presentation layer to do, not SQL Server.

Comment: @GordonLinoff i want to implement in mvc but i'm getting same result as like in sql so thats why i put my sql query

Comment: Please refer this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33138684/2451726)

Answer (score 0):

"tmp" part -- table to check query. You don't need it, it is for other readers :)

```sql
CREATE TABLE #tmpCatInfo (ID int, CategoryName varchar(55), ParentID int, IsActive int)
INSERT INTO #tmpCatInfo 
SELECT * FROM (VALUES (1, 'Toyota', NULL, 1)
                     ,(2, 'Honda', NULL, 1)
                     ,(3, 'Mitsubhi', NULL, 1)
                     ,(4, 'Toyota GLI', 1, 1)
                     ,(5, 'Toyota XLI', 1, 1)
                     ,(6, 'Swift', 1, 1)
                     ,(7, 'Honda Civic', 2, 1)
                     ,(8, 'Honda City', 2, 1)) a(ID, CategoryName, ParentID, IsActive)
;

-- USE THIS PART
-- Change #tmpCatInfo on your table name

WITH CategoryInfo (ID, CategoryName, IsActive, Model)
AS
(
SELECT ci.ID            as ID
     , ci.CategoryName  as CategoryName
     , ci2.IsActive     as IsActive
     , ci2.CategoryName as Model
FROM #tmpCatInfo ci
JOIN #tmpCatInfo ci2 ON ci.ID = ci2.ParentID
)

SELECT CASE 
         WHEN row_number() over (PARTITION BY CategoryName ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) = 1
         THEN CategoryName
       END AS 
      CatogoryName
    , Model
FROM CategoryInfo

-- USE THIS PART
```

Comment: Please See the above Edit Post to get better understanding about my Table Structure

Comment: @AbdulAleemSolutions hello?

Comment: sorry bro i was busy but yeah i have done with application level. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Like Gordon Linoff already told you: You should do this in your application and not in your DB.

Here an Example why your idea would cause trouble:

```
// Let's create a DataTable which holds the recors you want to get from the db
DataTable dt = new DataTable();
dt.Columns.Add("Category Name");
dt.Columns.Add("Model");

// Let's put in data
dt.Rows.Add(new[] { "Honda", "Honda City" });
dt.Rows.Add(new[] { null, "Honda Civic" });
dt.Rows.Add(new[] { "Toyota", "Swift" });
dt.Rows.Add(new[] { null, "Toyota GLI" });
dt.Rows.Add(new[] { null, "Toyota XLI" });

// dt is now what you want to get from your db.

// Let's see what we got:
Console.WriteLine(dt.Columns[0].ColumnName.PadRight(20) + dt.Columns[1].ColumnName.PadRight(20)); // PadRight to make it look better..
foreach (DataRow item in dt.Rows)
{
    Console.WriteLine((item[0] + "").PadRight(20) + (item[1] + "").PadRight(20));
}
```

We got the output you wanted:

```
Category Name       Model
Honda               Honda City
                    Honda Civic
Toyota              Swift
                    Toyota GLI
                    Toyota XLII
```

But you can't work with this data. Let's see what happens if you do something in your app with it:

```
Console.WriteLine("".PadRight(50, '-')); // Horizontal line to see 1st and 2nd output better

// Now we want to play with our data, by removing the 3rd Row:
dt.Rows.RemoveAt(2); // Index 2 is the 3rd row

// Let's see what we got after removing:
Console.WriteLine(dt.Columns[0].ColumnName.PadRight(20) + dt.Columns[1].ColumnName.PadRight(20)); // PadRight to make it look better..
foreach (DataRow item in dt.Rows)
{
    Console.WriteLine((item[0] + "").PadRight(20) + (item[1] + "").PadRight(20));
}
```

The output shows all Toyotas in the category Honda:

```
Category Name       Model
Honda               Honda City
                    Honda Civic
                    Toyota GLI
                    Toyota XLI
```

Comment: Actually i'm not trying to fit values by hard coding it should be dynamically retrive

Comment: Please See the above Edit Post to get better understanding about my Table Structure

Comment: @kara is right here, you have to handle such things in server side. The question is what you intent to do with this result ? You can always group by category name and extract model names.

Comment: yeah you are right I have done with application level